# Change users input but store original input separately

Tags: arrays, ruby, input, store

My assignment is to take the user's input and change every 'c' and 's' to 's' and 'th'.

After that it asked me to store the original user's input so it would not get changed.

I can't figure it out in Ruby.

```
print "What can we do for you?"
    user_input = gets.chomp
    user_input.downcase!
if user_input.length == 0
    puts "Well you will have to write something...!"
elsif user_input.include?("s") || user_input.include?("c")
    puts "We got ourselves some 's's and some 'c's"
    user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
    user_input.gsub!(/c/, "s")
    puts "The changed version: '#{user_input}!'"
else 
    print "Nope, no 's' or 'c' found"
end
```

Comment: [Like that?](https://repl.it/C1lw)

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please read http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use inplace version of `gsub`:

```
# user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
# user_input.gsub!(/c/, "s")

gsubbed = user_input.gsub(/s/, "th").gsub(/c/, "s")
puts "Changed version: '#{gsubbed}'"
puts "Original version: '#{user_input}'"
```

Note the lack of exclamation signs in functions names.

Comment: but how would i print it out changed then? If i just remove the "!" then it wont change the output to the user

Comment: Mind to try to execute the code I provided? In `gsubbed` there is a changed version, `user_input` is left intact.